# Is it OK to remove some 2x4 bracing in my attic?

Tags: wood, attic

I have a four year old house in North Carolina.  I would like to remove some 2x4 braces to facilitate room for  better storage.

The boards appear to be temporary from construction.

What do you think?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange, you should take the tour to help with our format. I would not remove anything from your description as you may think it is temporary but it may be important. With the cost of materials we don’t normally leave a lot of temporary supports when done. A photo may help clear this question up.

Comment: Almost certainly not, even without a picture. Very likely you are talking about bracing which keeps your roof from collapsing like a set of dominoes when the wind blows. That's exactly as "temporary" as the house is; or vice versa.

Comment: I was able to reconfigure some bracing for better storage, but I understood the loads involved and exactly what the "extra" bracing was for.  Don't remove anything.  Pictures might show that it is unnecessary, but chances are good that it does something.

Comment: Definitely need a picture. Also, what is the "storage" bearing on? (Size and spacing of lumber.) What density of storage are we talking about? (Xmas decorations are different from boxes of books.)

Comment: Is there a picture that you were going to post? The question as is is unanswerable and I vote to close it. If you update it then I will change my vote

Comment: It's very common for truss manufacturers to specify a hefty schedule of bracing to be installed by the carpenters. In many cases this simply involves sistering lumber onto the webbing of the truss. It doesn't look like it does much, but it provides critical stiffness for high-load situations such as snow and wind.

Comment: If this bracing is supposed to do something, it sure can't be doing it very well.

Answer (score 1):

Consult a structural engineer.

Bracing generally does look 'temporarily' built. It can, however, cause your roof to twist sideways if it isn't in place.